# definition of chain rule and Leibniz notation

Tags: calculus

i learned chain rule and i understood its definition like the following:

if there exist $f'(g(a))$ and $g'(a)$ at point $a$,

$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}=\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}×\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$

and i learned $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Here is a question :

1. Is it right that $\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}=\lim_{g(x)\to g(a)}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}$
2. Or Is it right that
   $\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}$

they are actually different, because no.2 fomula requires that g is continuous at point $a$.

which one is right?
i am freshmen student. I really need your help!

Comment: If $g$ is continuous in point $a$, it's the same because $x\to a$ implies $g(x) \to g(a)$

Comment: @JeanMarie yes.. That "g'(a) does exist" implies that "g(x) is continous at a". but i want to know that what if we don't know whether g'(a) exists? then which one i have to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid notation such as $\tfrac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}$ and $\lim\limits_{g(x) \to g(a)}$. Such expressions are not really well-defined (in my view), and will most likely only confuse you.

The notation $f'(g(a))$, on the other hand, is unambiguous. It's just the function $f'$ evaluated at the point $g(a)$:
$$
\lim_{y \to g(a)} \frac{f(y) - f(g(a))}{y - g(a)}
.
$$

Comment: oh... thanks a lot. it seems y is obviously NEW variable.. is it right??

Comment: You could replace $y$ with any (otherwise unused) letter that you like, and it wouldn't make any difference. But I thought that it would be unnatural to use $x$ here, since you're writing $g$ as a function of $x$, not $f$. So I chose to write $f$ as a function of $y$ instead.

Comment: it seems ...  maybe this is right. In a "rigorous" way to prove chain rule, i had likely seen that f'(g(a)) should work with NEW variable to avoid dividing zero problem.

Comment: I have ended up understanding these things completely. thanks a lot! you saved me from ambiguous. i think we MUST use like this y(any letter)->g(a).